# How to fix divs not positioned beside each other

Tags: css

I want to position 2 divs beside each other under a navigation bar. However, the left div seems to have an invisible portion that forces my introduction header right of its intended position. Im not able to figure out how to remove this invisible portion. As you can tell, I'm just starting to learn html so I would be thankful for some guidance. Help much appreciated!

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: #F2C369;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.div-container {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  width: 70%;
  position: relative;
  left: 15%;
}

.left-div {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.right-div {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  position: relative;
  left: 20%;
  width: 77%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.introduction {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="all-articles.html">All articles</a>
  <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
  <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>

<div class="div-container">

  <div class="left-div">

    <p>Links</p>
    <p>Links go here</p>

  </div>

  <div class="right-div">

    <div class="introduction">

      <h2>Introduction to webpage</h2>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ex animal incorrupte
        vel, fuisset fierent ut eam, per semper corrumpit
        adversarium ut. Accumsan adversarium mei ei. Has
        ne veniam inermis dissentias, id sed nibh
        legendos. Vix vivendo scriptorem definitionem ut.
        Cum delenit inimicus et, vis homero libris
        nostrud cu. Sed ei utamur honestatis interesset,
        eu utroque ancillae has. Usu ea habeo iusto,
        rebum cetero elaboraret duo ei. Sea oratio dicant
        dissentiet cu.orem ipsum dolor sit amet, ex
        animal incorrupte vel, fuisset fierent ut eam,
        per semper corrumpit adversarium ut. Accumsan
        adversarium mei ei. Has ne veniam inermis
        dissentias, id sed nibh legendos. Vix vivendo
        scriptorem definitionem ut.
      </p>

    </div>


  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use absolute positioning, split them using percentages.

try below code snippet.

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: #F2C369;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.div-container {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  width: 70%;
  position: relative;
  left: 15%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  clear: both;
}

.left-div {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
}

.right-div {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;

  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 75%;
}

.introduction {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="all-articles.html">All articles</a>
  <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
  <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>

<div class="div-container">

  <div class="left-div">

    <p>Links</p>
    <p>Links go here</p>

  </div>

  <div class="right-div">

    <div class="introduction">

      <h2>Introduction to webpage</h2>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ex animal incorrupte
        vel, fuisset fierent ut eam, per semper corrumpit
        adversarium ut. Accumsan adversarium mei ei. Has
        ne veniam inermis dissentias, id sed nibh
        legendos. Vix vivendo scriptorem definitionem ut.
        Cum delenit inimicus et, vis homero libris
        nostrud cu. Sed ei utamur honestatis interesset,
        eu utroque ancillae has. Usu ea habeo iusto,
        rebum cetero elaboraret duo ei. Sea oratio dicant
        dissentiet cu.orem ipsum dolor sit amet, ex
        animal incorrupte vel, fuisset fierent ut eam,
        per semper corrumpit adversarium ut. Accumsan
        adversarium mei ei. Has ne veniam inermis
        dissentias, id sed nibh legendos. Vix vivendo
        scriptorem definitionem ut.
      </p>

    </div>


  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I do not understand why using absolute positioning worked, but thanks! This solved it.

Comment: Please use clea:both on parent div as you can see height of  the background div has become 0.. please update you answer. I will suggest to use flex to align the div next to each other.  Incase if you want to make it responsive then it will be a prob for you. thanks

Comment: @XenioGracias Thanks :) .. for now i'll use `clear:both` on parent. i could use flex but @clearblueskies doesn't mention anything related to responsive.

Comment: @XenioGracias i think clearblueskies  got his answer already. but as enhancement you can post your answer too :)

Comment: @XenioGracias Thanks for your input, your answer was helpful too